# Virus in Subversion repository, what to do?

Tags: svn, antivirus

Imagine the following situation:

1. A virus infected file was commited into a Subversion repository.
2. A Anti Virus scanner runs on the server and also scans the Subversion repository.

The Anti Virus scanner will delete the affected revision or move it to quarantine. The consequence is a broken repository.

If the revision file is recoverable (from quarantine), how to solve this problem?
I have some goals to achieve:

1. The AV is not allowed to be disabled or excluded from the directories.
2. The virus infected file must not be stored in the repository
3. The repository must be consistens and usable.

What is the nicest solution for this little problem?

Comment: Can you rebuild the infected file from source? If you can, frag the virus from the repo, rebuild, and recommit.

Comment: Most likely the virusscanner won't detect the virus in the revision file as most scanners scan only interesting places of files and a revision file is a binary diff format which most likely breaks pattern scanners.

Comment: qor72: I don't know the infected file, that's the problem.
Bert: The scanner detected it, that's my problem. I haven't thought it, too :)

Comment: 1. Temporarily disable AV.  2. Dump-Filter-Load repository to remove infected file.  3.  Reactivate virus scanner.  4. Fire the in-duh-vidual who checked in the infected file.

Comment: Amardeep: It was a false positive. The Dump Filter load won't work, because the file was scrubbed. At least a happy end entered: The file was in quarantine and the virus scanner got a signature update. It all went well.

Comment: The best: Ask your IT Dept to add your repos in Exclusions or the AV to only report and ignore. Most of times such repo-breakers are false positives.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal):

> There are special cases where you
>   might want to destroy all evidence of
>   a file or commit. (Perhaps somebody
>   accidentally committed a confidential
>   document.) This isn't so easy, because
>   Subversion is deliberately designed to
>   never lose information. Revisions are
>   immutable trees which build upon one
>   another. Removing a revision from
>   history would cause a domino effect,
>   creating chaos in all subsequent
>   revisions and possibly invalidating
>   all working copies.
>
> The project has plans, however, to
>   someday implement an svnadmin
>   obliterate command which would
>   accomplish the task of permanently
>   deleting information. (See [issue 516](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=516).)
>
> In the meantime, your only recourse is
>   to svnadmin dump your repository, then
>   pipe the dumpfile through
>   svndumpfilter (excluding the bad path)
>   into an svnadmin load command. See
>   [chapter 5](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.html) of the Subversion book for
>   details about this.

Comment: svndumpfilter is the only answer short of restoring from backup.  +1

Answer (score 3):

The easiest?  Restore from a backup from before the commit with the virus...

Comment: The revision is older than one year. Or better said: > 6000 revisions old. Backup won't do it.

Comment: I have backups, lots and lots. If I restore a backup before the commit, I lose > 6000 revisions. that's not feasible.

Comment: Why couldn't you just revert that one file to before it had the virus?

Answer (score 0):

If you created the repository in file mode (single repo file per source file) then you can probably fix/edit/replace the infected file.
If you created it in DB mode then it's harder - you can svndump then svncreate a new repo, but it's probably easier to exclude the SVN repository from the virus scan

Comment: The revision file is infected, so no replace/edit whatever is possible.

Answer (score 0):

"The AV is not allowed to be disabled or excluded from the directories."

Fight with your IT Department to add your repos in exclusions. BEST, if the AV supports "Informative only mode", make it work with your repos in informative only mode. Most times, such old viruses are just false positives. Add precommit hooks to virus-scan any file and reject the commit if it is flagged by a virus.

If the AV reports old file being infected, check if not false positive. If it's not, and file is really old virus, just commit its deletion and ignore its existence in your history altogether.